# Sublime Text Command Palette for playing macro

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible to play a saved macro using the command palette?

I know that it is possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to a macro but that is another thing to remember and not very feasible when you have more than a few macros.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible. You need to save your macro to a file at ../sublime-text-3/Packages/User/`YOUR_MACRO_NAME`.sublime-macro. Then add the following code to file ../sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Default.sublime-commands:

```
[
    {
    "caption": "ADD TEXT TO BE DISPLAYED ON COMMAND PALETTE",
    "command": "run_macro_file",
    "args":
        {
            "file": "res://Packages/User/YOUR_MACRO_NAME.sublime-macro"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to run a macro from the command palette but I have found the [Macroptimize](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Macroptimize) package to be helpful in running my macros - one hotkey gives you a list of defined macros to choose from. Not quite what you're looking for but perhaps it will be helpful.